# Can't initialiaze m_days[month][day]= an object

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

```
class App
{
public:
    App();
    void someFunction();
private:
    QList<QList<Date *> > m_days;
};

void App::someFunction() {
   Date * a;
   a = new Date;
   qDebug() << "A";
   m_days[0][0]= a;  // [month][day]
   qDebug() << "B";
```

Output is:

```
A
```

It crashes right away. It crashes on the line of `qDebug "A"`.I cannot find what is wrong with the code. Any help would be nice!

Comment: `QList<QList<Date *> m_days;` is not valid C++ syntax. PS: maybe inserting  a Qlist in the first Qlist might be a good starting point

Comment: Declaring a QList doesn't make it have any contents.  So when you access the first member, `[0]`, it is undefined.  Why doing you make your constructor make a temporary QList of 31 new `Date`, then `push_back` that to `m_days`.  Do it 12 times so you have 12 QLists of  31 Dates inside your class member

Comment: on second thought a QLIst of `nullptr` is probably better as the inner initial QList

Comment: @Berto99 yes its missing here but not in my code. Forgot to put the > here

Comment: @infixed  I'll try this tomorrow. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m_days` is not a fixed array, it is a dynamic list.  `m_days` is initially empty, and you are not adding any elements to it, so using its `operator[]` to access non-existant elements is **undefined behavior**.

Also, you have a syntax error on your declaration of `m_days`.  It is missing an `>` on the outer template.

Try this instead:

```cpp
class App
{
public:
    App();
    void someFunction();
private:
    QList<QList<Date*> > m_days;
};

void App::someFunction() {
   a = new Date;
   qDebug() << "A";

   QList<Date*> elem;
   elem.push_back(a); // or: elem.append(a);
   m_days.push_back(elem); // or: m_days.append(elem);

   qDebug() << "B";

...
```